# How do I tie an enum to a set of numeric values?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula

I created a list of items Data Validation in a sheet corresponding to time-frequency:

`weekly,monthly,annually`

I want to multiply values in a numeric column with the corresponding weekly values to get a normalized annual cost so weekly would be 52x, monthly 12x.

It's just three columns: one numerical, one with drop down of 3 possible text values (weekly, etc) and a final numerical (annual total). If I choose weekly from the drop down, I want the value in the first column to be multiplied by 52 and the result stored in the 3rd total column.

How do I accomplish this in Google Sheets?

Comment: It's got private data. What do you want from it?

Comment: It's just three columns: one numerical, one with drop down of 3 possible text values (weekly, etc) and a final numerical (annual total). If I choose weekly from the drop down, I want the value in the first column to be multiplied by 52 and the result stored in the 3rd total column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B1:B="weekly";   A1:A*52;
              IF(B1:B="monthly";  A1:A*12;
              IF(B1:B="annually"; A1:A*1; ))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
=IF(B1="weekly";   A1*52;
 IF(B1="monthly";  A1*12;
 IF(B1="annually"; A1*1; )))
```

[image: 6]